# C# unit testing mocking service ignoring return

Tags: c#, moq, autofixture

I am writing some unit tests to test a controller. In that controller there is a call to a service.  In my test I want to mock the service call and obviously specify the desired return.

When the code runs it goes into the controller and when it reaches the service I can clearly see that it is using my mock.  However, the return value of the mock is always null and not the return that I specified (i.e. `expectedItem`). Any idea?

#### Unit test against controller's action

```cs
public class SearchIATeamControllerTests : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SearchIATeamController _sut;
    private IFixture _fixture;

    public SearchIATeamControllerTests()
    {
        _fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
        _sut = _fixture.Create<SearchIATeamController>();
    }


    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_team_name_with_ia_team_name_returns_ok()
    {
        // Arrange
        var expectedResultItem = _fixture.Create<SearchIATeamResponse>();

        var expectedItem = new List<SearchIATeamResponse>
        {
            expectedResultItem
        };

        var mockIATeamService = _fixture.Create<Mock<IIATeamSearchService>>();
        mockIATeamService.Setup(m => m.GetIATeamName(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(expectedItem);

        // Act
        var result = await _sut.Get("test").ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Names have been abbreviated for brevity.

#### System Under Test

```
public async Task<ActionResult<SearchIATeamResponse>> Get([FromQuery] string iATeamName)
{   
    if (iATeamName == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    try
    {
        var result = await _searchIATeamService.GetIATeamName(iATeamName);

        if (!result.Any())
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(result);

     }
     catch (ArgumentException ex)
     {
         return BadRequest(ex.Message);
     }      
}
```

Comment: This is almost always from your `Setup` mocking the wrong thing. Try setting the mock to strict mode and see if that gives you any hints.

Comment: Can you show the code that is being unit tested so we can see how the GetIATeamName method is being called.

Comment: @IanSoc added now.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior strict mode did not shed any light.

Comment: Did strict mode cause the call to throw an exception, or did the mock continue returning null?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior no exception thrown, my test completed but failed as the expected result was not what I wanted.  Mock continued to return null.

Comment: That indicates that your service is using a different instance than the one that you're invoking Setup on, right? I'm fleshing out my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One key point here is that you're using AutoFixture to create both your Mock and your service. In order to ensure that you're using the same mock instance for your Setup as the one that got injected into the service, you'll probably want to `Freeze` the mock instance prior to creating the service.

```
public class SearchIATeamControllerTests : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SearchIATeamController _sut;
    private readonly Mock<IIATeamSearchService> _mockIATeamService;
    private IFixture _fixture;

    public SearchIATeamControllerTests()
    {
        _fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
        _mockIATeamService = _fixture.Freeze<Mock<IIATeamSearchService>>();
        _sut = _fixture.Create<SearchIATeamController>();
    }


    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_team_name_with_ia_team_name_returns_ok()
    {
        // Arrange
        var expectedResultItem = _fixture.Create<SearchIATeamResponse>();

        var expectedItem = new List<SearchIATeamResponse>
        {
            expectedResultItem
        };

        _mockIATeamService.Setup(m => m.GetIATeamName(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(expectedItem);

        // Act
        var result = await _sut.Get("test").ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Note that I captured the result of the `Freeze` so it's easier to use in test methods. This is a pattern I like, but you could theoretically continue using `_fixture.Create<>()` in your methods if you prefer not to have another private field hanging about.

Comment: All looks OK apart from this line   _mockIATeamService.Create<Mock<IIATeamSearchService>>();  Can't invoke Create on it.

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy/paste mistake. Fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately the code above has the same issue, it doesn't use the return specified in the mock in expectedItem.

Comment: @LeedsWalker: Are you sure you used the code as I have it here? The behavior you describe would happen if you put the `_mockIATeamService` initialization after the `_sut` initialization.

Comment: Yes you are correct, as long as controller creation happens after the mock freeze then it works fine.  In my previous example i created the controller in the constructor and did the mock later in the test which meant it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused by the order - the controller should only be declared after the mock service set up and not in the constructor.

Comment: I haven't used AutoFixture before. From first glance and also seeing that you must declare the controller after setup of the mocks are done, seems to me very unhandy. The test class looks so difficult. I use Moq and XUnit, together with AutoSetup (a nuget library I wrote). AutoSetup can create the mocks for a class under test as part of the constructor. The order does not matter. You can setup the mock in your test method. A test class with this approach is so much cleaner. Just wanted to leave a comment in case you want to take a look at other libraries. https://github.com/tukaya/autosetup

Comment: This does not jive with my experience. I have plenty of code where I create the subject under test in the Test Setup method, and then only add mocking behavior later. The only order that should matter is whether you freeze your mock before creating the controller.